Nuxt 3 useFetch is not sending request
I use useFetch from Nuxt 3 in a Pinia function to log in a user. The first time the function is called, the request is sent successfully and the behaviour is as expected.
On the second call, e.g. after the user has changed the API key, no request is sent. I have checked this using the network tab.
My desired behaviour would be that every time I call the method, I also send a query to my backend.
Pinia user.ts
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useApiFetch } from '~/composables/useApiFetch'

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
  const user = ref({})

  async function handleLogin(apiKey: string) {
    const { data, error } = await useApiFetch('/user/login', {
      params: {
        apiKey
      },
      watch: false,
    })

    user.value = data.value
    console.log(user.value)
  }

  return {
    handleLogin,
    user
  }
})

index.vue page
<template>
  <div class="h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
    <div
      class="surface-card p-12 shadow-2 border-round lg:w-1/3 shadow-gray-400 shadow-2xl rounded border-primary-500">
      <div class="text-center mb-5">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/200x70" alt="Image" class="mb-3 mx-auto" />
        <div class="text-900 text-3xl font-medium mb-3">Welcome Back</div>
        <span class="text-600 font-medium line-height-3">Please use a public torn api key to access.</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="apikey" class="block text-900 font-medium mb-2">API Key</label>
        <InputText
            id="apikey" v-model="apiKey"
            :invalid="apiKey.length !== 16 && apiKey.length > 0"
            :disabled="isLoading"
            type="text"
            class="w-full mb-3"
        />


        <Button label="Sign In" icon="pi pi-user" :loading="isLoading" class="w-full" @click="handleLogin"></Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useUserStore } from '~/stores/user.ts'

const userStore = useUserStore()

const apiKey = ref('')
const isLoading = ref(false)

async function handleLogin() {
  isLoading.value = true

  await userStore.handleLogin(apiKey.value)

  isLoading.value = false
}
</script>

my useApiFetch:
import { defu } from 'defu'
import { useUserStore } from '~/stores/user'

export function useApiFetch(url: string, options = {}) {
  const { $toast } = useNuxtApp()
  const uS = useUserStore()

  const { user } = storeToRefs(uS)

  const defaults = {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3001',
    onRequest({ request, options }) {
      // Set the request headers
      options.headers = options.headers || {
        apiKey: user.value.apiKey,
      }
    },
    onRequestError({ request, options, error }) {
      console.log('onRequestError', error)
    },
    // onResponse({ request, response, options }) {
    //   // Process the response data
    //   localStorage.setItem('token', response._data.token)
    // },
    onResponseError({ request, response, options }) {
      // Handle the response errors
      $toast.add({
        severity: 'error',
        summary: 'Error',
        detail: response._data.error.error,
      })
    },
  }

  const params = defu(options, defaults)

  return useFetch(url, params)
}


useApiFetch is not shown

edited to my OP

Hello, I checked your code and compared it to the documentation, and I think you didn't define the actions correctly https://dev.to/rafaelmagalhaes/pinia-and-nuxt-3-4ij5 , hence the function was only called once on initialization. Try redefining the store again by following this example and see if it works.

@artikandri This is not the case. The article shows store options, and the OP uses store function, both are ok.

@OliverKhl I'm not sure what happens here, this sounds like caching behaviour which nuxt is capable of but it's not supposed to be enabled by default. It looks like useFetch is kind of misused, it's a composable but is used as a replacement for fetch(). It's unnecessary this contributes to the problem, but it can. Generally "use" function is called once at component setup (or store setup when it's allowed). In the case of useFetch it's called with immediate:false and then a request is retriggered on refresh() in handleLogin when reactive data in params is changed.

@EstusFlask what is the best practices in that case? Using axios? Maybe $fetch or something like vueUse useFetch?

As noted, it's something like const apiKey = ref(); const { data: loginData, refresh: loginRefresh } = useApiFetch('/user/login', { params: { apiKey }, immediate: false } directly inside useUserStore. And useUserStore() needs to be moved inside onRequest to work around circular dependency. Can't say if this will solve the actual problem though

UseFetch is more of a lifecycle hook. Use refresh on it if you want to call it back even tho this is still quite an anti-pattern IMO: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#return-values You can also use $fetch if you want something simpler.
